# Cant update ChartJS data from $scope.data

Tags: angularjs, charts

I want to update the data of my Chartjs chart dynamically using AngularJS. The chart works fine if there is no data being updated, but if I try to update the data by using a $interval function the chart just remains blank.

```
   $scope.labelsx2 = [];
    $scope.seriesx2 = [];
    $scope.datax2 = [
        [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    ];  

    $scope.randomize = function () {


         $scope.datax2 = [65, 59, 1, 81, 1, 55, 1];
         console.log('workk');


    };

    $interval(function() {$scope.randomize();},1000,0);


    <div class="item item-text-wrap">

        <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" data="datax2" labels="labelsx2" legend="true" series="seriesx2" options="{showTooltips: false}"></canvas>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$scope.datax2 = [65, 59, 1, 81, 1, 55, 1];
```

in randomise function with

```
$scope.datax2 = [[65, 59, 1, 81, 1, 55, 1]];
```